# Don't understand why I need a return on the last lines

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

I'm solving a problem about figuring out the minimum path to a leaf in a tree. I'm using BFS in C++ with a queue that stores a node and the current depth.

I traverse the tree in BFS adding nodes to my queue as I go along. As soon as I reach my first leaf I exit my cycle.

I don't understand why I need to add the return 0; line at the end of the program (commented on the code).

If I remove that line I get an error saying that the function got to the end without a return.

In which case will I need it?

```
class TreeDepth{
    TreeNode* node;
    int depth;
    public:
    TreeDepth(int depth, TreeNode* node): depth(depth), node(node) {}
    TreeNode* getNode() {return node;}
    int getDepth() {return depth;}
};
class Solution {
public:
    int minDepth(TreeNode* root) {
        if(!root)
            return 0;
        else
        {
            std::queue<TreeDepth> depthQ;
            TreeDepth nodeDepth(1,root);
            depthQ.push(nodeDepth);
            while(!depthQ.empty())
            {
                TreeDepth currentNode = depthQ.front();
                depthQ.pop();
                if(!currentNode.getNode()->left && !currentNode.getNode()->right)
                    return currentNode.getDepth();
                else
                {
                    if(currentNode.getNode()->left)
                    {
                        TreeDepth leftNodeDepth(currentNode.getDepth() + 1, currentNode.getNode()->left);
                        depthQ.push(leftNodeDepth);
                    }
                    if(currentNode.getNode()->right)
                    {
                        TreeDepth rightNodeDepth(currentNode.getDepth() + 1, currentNode.getNode()->right);
                        depthQ.push(rightNodeDepth);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    return 0; // why do I need this line?
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't return anything from your inner `else`.

Comment: If you **know** that your loop will never terminate (which appears to be the case, since you either return or add something to the depth queue), why make it a while at all?  Just use an infinite loop (`for(;;)` or `while(true)`).  Then the compiler will be able to tell that execution will never reach the end of the function.

Comment: You're stuck. The compiler doesn't know that your loop will never fall off the end, so you get a warning that you need a return statement. But if you add that return statement some other compiler will warn you that you have unreachable code. If you compile with a setting that turns warnings into errors you'll have to conditionalize the code to make both compilers happy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have paths in the function that exit but don't return a value. For instance, if depthQ IS empty, your code would exit without returning anything (but for that final 'return 0'). And you've declared your function to return an int. So all code paths must return some int.

Comment: But how can depthQ be empty if inside the else I always add something to it? The condition on the first if guarantees that the if's inside the else will have a true condition in at least one of them (I think?).

Comment: @JoaoAntunes But the compiler doesn't know that, and it isn't going to spend the effort to try and recognize that.  So it issues the diagnostic.

Comment: I understand. So in reality, the line will never be run?

Comment: Yes, except for: is your code free of other bugs? Is depthQ free of bugs? Does depthQ always do what you think it does? What if depthQ runs out of memory? Is there some weird tree shape that messes with your code? etc... 'never' is tricky!